# Knockout mapping array not updated when deleting elements

Tags: javascript, ajax, knockout.js, data-binding

I've ran into this kind of issue before and the solution 'clicked' for me as i was writing the post but now it eludes me. Knockout.js's observable array won;t remove data when model is updated... (using mapping plugin).

Namely, I have a view model which i get by using:

`var model = knockout.mapping.fromJS(Data, {}, ko.mapping.fromJS({}))`

Whenever I get an AJAX response from the server I am running the following code:

`knockout.mapping.fromJS(Data, {}, model);`

(it is essentially the call to the same function however if `model` is not defined it creates one based on an empty object instead - meaning the first time it is fired - every other time, it is suppose to **update** the model.

The model is afterwards applied to the HTML using:

`ko.applyBindings(model, document.getElementById('idhere'));`

Now any new data i get is bound properly, any change of scenery such as moving from one model structure to another, works like a charm.... However when I try to *update* an existing Observable Array within a model with fresh set of data from the server, in case of:

1. Adding new data, the array gets updated, i can see it in the model.
2. Changing the data of one of the elements also worked, the model gets updated.
3. However deleting the data from the array leaves the deleted data in the model.
4. Furthermore the #3 only happens in case i delete anything other then the last element in the array. Last element of the array gets deleted just fine without any issues, so it acts as if I can only "remove the last element". If I remove any element but the last one, all of them are still in the model after the **"update"**

I feel as if knockout doesn't know that I want the elements deleted so when it sees them gone it doesn't "update" the changes thinking that I only wanted to 'add more elements' of which there are none since the AJAX only brought back a reduced list (compared to the one my client has).

### **EDIT:**

As per request the HTML which relates to the binding of the said observable array:

```
<!-- ko foreach: model.dataSets.RoomsInSuite -->
<span data-bind="text: Name"></span>
<!-- /ko -->
```

The array itself contains objects such as:

```
RoomsInSuite = [
{Name: "Room1", Type: "Bedroom"},
{Name: "Room2", Type: "Kitchen"},
{Name: "Room3", Type: "LivingRoom"},
{Name: "Room4", Type: "Bathroom"},
]
```

this is enough of an example. Once again, the binding is a non issue, it works. If i extract the model by using `knockout.mapping.toJS(model)` and view it, the Observable Array (RoomInSuite) never gets it's elements removed even though server returned a JSON with not all of them present. It gets removed fine if i delete the last element of the array but fails for any other case.

### EDIT - Solution (ish)

Okay so after spending an entire day banging my head against the wall, I figured out what the issue was. Has nothing to do with knockout. Server was serving me with a different JSON for cases where:

1. Last row of data was deleted.
2. Any row (other then the last one) of data was deleted.

Mainly since PHP's array's do not get re-indexed when you remove elements, the conversion on PHP's side from an array-like structure to JSON was creating an syntax like:

`["0":{datahere}, "1": {datahere}, "2":{datahere}]` in case of (A), and

`{ "0": {datahere}, "3": {datahere}}` in case of (B),

the issue being, once we convert that into javascript, one is an object the other is an array, and knockout cannot update an array with an object. I just was not able to see the different brackets since this thing is deep nested in a forest of other objects and arrays so it got away.

Comment: can you provide more code and the related html bindings for the obervableArray?

Comment: @gkb updated the question as per request.

Comment: @Dellirium if you can add some repro using fiddle/jsbin would be easy .

Comment: @supercool i mean the entire model is wrapped in like crazy amount of class related code which is something i cannot copy to the bin/fiddle. The topic i posted above I just an excerpt. Hypothetically speaking, is the updating the way that I described above using `knockout.mapping.fromJS(Data, {}, oldModelReference)` suppose to work correctly? What makes it really strange is that it all works when I delete the last member of an array but not for any other. I do not know if the "model update" syntax given above is correct.

Comment: @Dellirium can you try updating this http://jsfiddle.net/Mmt9F/32/ . even u can map ur ko version's as i'm not sure what excatly ur using .

Comment: @supercool i've written comments describing the behaviour in the JS section in here, take a loot, though, apparently it is not of issue: http://jsfiddle.net/Mmt9F/36/

Comment: @Dellirium this should help to resolve all issues you're facing http://jsfiddle.net/Mmt9F/38/ . if you are using server returned object just for display with no edit on data avoid mapping(not req'd) .

Comment: @supercool Yes i was going nuts yesterday, mostly because of non-consistent behavior, which we all know is the worst thing when it comes to debugging.... figured out what the issue was and will update the question to reflect it. Has nothing to do with knockout, as per usual it's the damn server-side's fault.

Comment: @supercool I need the mapping because its a web-app so there is a lot of editing, it helps, a lot. Either way it was a server issue as said, bad JSON structure, having {} instead of [] after deleting an element that is not a last element.